# Структура блоков новостей

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, blocks

Есть блок новостей, который будет копироваться до 8 статей на одной странице, собственно, для этого нужна определенная структура.
Например, если не вложить в новость картинку, то в моей форме будет пустой блок со своим размером и цветом, а нужно, чтобы его вовсе не было. Ко всему этому должно быть единое положение.
Примеры:
Моя текущая форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Желаемая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как организовать отсутвие картинки - не знаю, а вот выоровнять блок своими силами может и получится.
Желательно не советовать что-то стороннее, типа подключения плагинов, использование каких-то прочих файлов и т.д. Все желательно используя HTML, CSS и JS.

**Обновление**

Постоянное положение блоков на странице и их разный размер сделал, а вот как сделать проверку на наличие/отсутствие картинки - не знаю.

Код вывода:

```
<?php
    function random_html_color()
    {
        return sprintf('#%02X%02X%02X', rand(230, 255), rand(230, 255), rand(230, 255));
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($news); $i++) {
        echo '
            <a href = "" class = "hrefBN">
                <div class = "wrapperNews">
                    <div class="blocksNews" style = "background-color: '.random_html_color().'">
                        <img src="" alt="" class="imgBN">
                        <a href="" class="txtASubNews">'.$news[$i]["title"].'</a>
                        <p class="txtPNews">'.$news[$i]["intro_text"].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю то у вас принципе сами картинки есть
Вам нужно узнать есть ли картинка конкретно к определенной $news ?
Так проверьте просто на наличие файла
Типа

```
if(is_file($path)) {

    <img src="" alt="" class="imgBN">

}
```

Comment: Немного другую проверку сделал, но в общем, получилось.